# Conditional replace in a Python list

Tags: python

The actual values are in a dictionary something like this,

```
{'logsource1': {'product': 'ABC', 'service': 'Proxy'},
 'logsource2': {'product': 'DEF', 'service': 'Proxy'},
 'condition': 'Join logsource1.selection1 and logsource2.selection3 AND ((logsource1.selection2 <= contraint1) AND (logsource2.selection4 <= constraint1))',
  'constraint1': {'Value': '5 minutes', 'Type': 'Datetime'}}}

l1 = ['Join', 'logsource1.selection1', 'and', 'logsource2.selection3', 'AND', '((logsource1.selection2', '<=', 'contraint1)', 'AND', '(logsource2.selection4', '<=', 'constraint1))']
```

I extracted the condition and added it to list l1 so that the find and replace would be easier. Similarly the actual values to be replaced with are also part of the same dictionary.

the output should be,

l1 = ['Join', 'ABC.selection1', 'and', 'DEF.selection3', 'AND', '((ABC.selection2', '<=', 'contraint1)', 'AND', '(DEF.selection4', '<=', 'constraint1))']

Comment: Stored as actual variables? Or a dictionary?

Comment: stored as dictionary

Comment: Can you share an example dictionary? And the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the values stored in a dictionary:

```
values = {
    'logsource1.selection1': 'foo',
    'logsource2.selection3': 'bar',
     # etc
}
```

Then you can iterate over the list positions and substitute:

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] in values:
        l1[i] = values[l1[i]]
```